# Is it possible to build a one-cubic-meter soundproof space? what is the minimal size of a soundproof space I could build?

Tags: sound-proofing

I am wondering if it is possible to build a one-cubic-meter soundproof space or other similar size of soundproof space.

Why would I need this? I am planning soundproof my house, although I am new to soundproof. So, if I can build a group of test spaces with different solutions, I can get a comparison result to decide which one is suitable to. the smaller the size of test space, the less cost I spend.

So, what is the minimal size of a soundproof space I could build?

Note: both inside and outside of the test space is full of the normal air as the daily environment we live in.

Comment: There's no minimum size really; it just depends how big the thing you need to put in it is.  I knew a guy who built a DIY [Anechoic chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber) of about the size you're talking about for testing his homemade loudspeakers.

Comment: I agree there is no minimum size but scale matters what works great for a small area may not work well on a large wall.+

Comment: @NateS. Is it possible to share his solution?

Comment: @EdBeal I agree with you. So I need to know how does each of the components work, I guess some of them works well in a suitable range, and I could find the ranges out.

Comment: @zghqh, not really, that was an old coworker that I no longer have contact info for unfortunately.

Comment: yes, a one cubic meter container with the air removed would definitely be a soundproof environment

Comment: Funny , no air but true.  I built some studios many years back, the wall surfaces were specified.  a space between the 2 recording rooms 2 walls and a space between the acoustic foam panels used on each side right down to the type of fasteners and the stagger from opposing sides. they provided the panels I built the walls hung the panels and you could not hear a gun shot between the 2 rooms (a starting pistol was there test). I bet if you google recording studio sound insulation there will be those pre made panels (hard back with many small holes and larger foam cones. The foam over laps edges

Comment: I just watched a video on soundproofing an hour ago, someone had linked it in another question. Turns out there is an industry standard for soundproofing including rating numbers (40=minimum, 60=quite good). So **don't reinvent the wheel**.

Comment: @EdBeal What does "no air but true" mean?

Comment: @zghqh With no air or in a vacuum sound cannot travel as jsotola was saying a 1 cubic meter with no air it would be sound proof I guess not many got the joke.

Comment: How small a container can you put a decent vacuum in? There's no sound in there. Vacuum sound insulation seems sadly underused to me. You get some sound coming thru necessary structural bracing, but a few minutes a day with a vacuum pump will give you darn good sound isolation.

Answer (score 1):

A small-scale model won't produce accurate results. You will have different standing waves, resonances, and modes in small cube than an odd-shaped real-life room. Different cube-lining materials *will* provide a baseline relative comparison, but the results shouldn't be extrapolated to a real-life situation without careful acoustical modeling.

Answer (score 0):

There has been extensive testing done with various ways of sound proofing and the amount of decibel drop achieved by each method and different methods combined. 
There are [staggered studs](https://www.thevitruviusproject.com/resources/stud-wall-design-for-a-quiet-living-space/), RC-1 channel on regular frame walls and on staggered studs, with one layer of sheetrock or 2 layers, ratings using [1 or 2 pound mass loaded vinyl mat](https://isostore.com/totalmass-mlv-barrier-1-pound-2-pound.html). Wall with insulation and more. It's out there to be read online, all you need is the keywords I have laid out for you.

But if you just want to have fun with it, then.....